# Determine whether module is enabled / disabled

Tags: drush

I am trying to write a Drush script to enable a bunch of modules based on a hook. If it's already enabled, I would rather skip enabling that module.

Is there a way for Drush to return whether or not a module is enabled?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This code will list all non core enabled modules:

```
drush pm-list --pipe --type=module --status=enabled --no-core
```

Comment: +1; and you can even pipe the results to [`find` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(command)) like this: `drush pm-list --pipe --type=module --status=enabled --no-core | find /I "views_ui"` - in this example, if "views_ui" is enabled, it returns `views_ui`, else it returns an empty result set (nothing).

Comment: @Sk8erPeter `grep` seems more efficient for this case

Answer (score 9):

```
drush pm-info
```

Gives status of module with additional information as given below:

```
drush pm-info <module_name>

 Extension        :  <ext>
 Project          :  Unknown
 Type             :  module
 Title            :  <title>
 Description      :  <desc>
 Version          :  6.x-1.0
 Date             :  1970-01-01
 Package          :  <pkg>
 Core             :  6.x
 PHP              :  5.3.5
 Status           :  enabled
 Path             :  <path_to_the_module>
 Schema version   :  <schema_version>
 Requires         :  none
 Required by      :  <list_of_modules_this_module_is_required_by>
 Configure        :  None
```

Comment: This command was removed in newer versions of Drush. Drush 10 says to instead use `pm-list`

Answer (score 3):

with drush 10 :

```
drush pm:list --type=module --status=enabled | grep mymodule
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner to get module status:

```
drush pm-info mymodule | grep Status | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs
```

Returns either `not installed` or `enabled`

**Explanation:**

- `drush pm-info mymodule` - gets info about the module
- `grep Status` - just get the status line
- `cut -d':' -f 2` - get the value after the colon
- `xargs` - remove the whitespace